# Errors when apt-get upgrade

Tags: 10.04, apt, update-alternatives

I recently updated an server from 8.04 to 10.04, the update ran basically flawlessly, but now every time i use apt-get I get strange error messages.

```
:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up gcj-4.4-jre-headless (4.4.3-1ubuntu4.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/rmid corrupt: invalid status
dpkg: error processing gcj-4.4-jre-headless (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcj-4.4-jre-headless
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I dont even use java on that machine. How can I get rid of it (apt-get remove or purge did not work).

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I could not find a solution, so I simply removed (deleted) all the files beginning with 
    gcj-4.4-jre-headless
 from the folder 
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/
 . I don't know if that was the best idea, but it worked. Good luck for everyone who reads this.